# Regular Expression result consistency issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Seem to be getting a very different output in my PHP code to online editors, the following websites both show that my pattern and string should match... It shows that it matches in the following websites:

http://www.phpliveregex.com/

https://regex101.com/

Can someone spot the issue here?

**Pattern**

```
$a= "/H(\d{7})_([\d\w]*)\n([\n\w\.]*?)V($b)_(\d)_(\d)_(\d*)(_([a-z_\d]*)($c)($c))/";
```

*Note the use of variables in this of $b & $c*

**String**

```
$buffer =   "H2241008_1211901000000013220
R001_1
W1443.91
Maa_01D11100000000000016210053_W802.83
Mab_02D21100000000000024210054_W1323.18
Mzz_00000000000000000000000000_W0.00
T1_
V15_0_1_1210_aa225400225459_aa233900234159
V16_0_1_1210_ab192500205059_aa225500225659
V17_0_1_1210_aa225100225359_aa234200234659
V18_0_1_1210_aa224900225059_aa233800233859_aa234700240159
V19_0_1_1210_aa224400224459_aa230400230459
V303_0_1_1210_aa225700230359_aa232700233759
V402_0_1_1210_aa230800232359_aa232600232659
V450_0_1_1210_aa224500224859
V614_0_1_1210_aa224300224359_aa230500230759_aa232400232559
V65535_0_1_1210_ab192500205059_aa224300240159";
$buffer = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $buffer);
```

**Getting Matches**

```
preg_match_all($a, $buffer, $matches);
preg_match_all("/H(\d{7})_([\d\w]*)\n([\n\w\.]*?)V(15)_(\d)_(\d)_(\d*)(_([a-z_\d]*)(2254[0-9]{2}|500)(2254[0-9]{2}|500))/", $buffer, $output_array);

var_dump($matches);
var_dump($output_array);
```

I've tried it two ways (to check against syntax vs. using variables in the pattern string or not) like this as I thought the `$`,`\w`,`\n` etc. would get in the way, but both return like this:

```
array(12) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } [3]=> array(0) { } [4]=> array(0) { } [5]=> array(0) { } [6]=> array(0) { } [7]=> array(0) { } [8]=> array(0) { } [9]=> array(0) { } [10]=> array(0) { } [11]=> array(0) { } }
```

What I expect; is to get one match, with 11 parts.  I thought it might be a PHP Regular Expression difference to other engines, but the **phpliveregex** gave the exact syntax as tried above (`$output_array`), and it returns exactly as expected.

Please help!

Comment: What values do `$b` and `$c` have for your given example buffer?

Comment: Using the actual values in the second `preg_match_all` line: $b = 15 and $c = 2254[0-9]{2}|500

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression you use the `\n` character (new line). You have to make sure that you have the correct line endings in your example string (and in your regex of course, depending on what you actually want to match).

Copying your example PHP code to [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) and choosing Format -> Unix (LF) before saving results in a populated `$output_array`.

If you want to match windows style line endings replace `\n` with `\r\n`.

Comment: Good catch, though in the actual file which this buffer snippet is from, the line endings are in fact \n (and yes, lives in a linux box); to rule it out of the equation however, I added `$buffer = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $buffer);` after it, but it made no change.  Had switched to using this snippet of the $buffer variable for the mean time till I make sure the regular expression is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like my `$buffer` was misleading.  I pasted it here, which did not have the indentation like I have in my code, and it was the extra characters in the indentation that was causing the issue.

Don't want to rock the boat, but I am now not also using double quotes for the variable of the regular expression -- just in case.  Desired result achieved.